# Run Python scripts directly or driven by webhook

Tags: quire-api

I've known Quire for its API. I do not seek integration with Apps. I want to run `Python` scripts directly or driven by `webhook` form. Any documentation or experience?

-- by Raúl García de Madinabeitia

Answer (score 1):

Here the documentation on [Webhooks in the Quire API](https://quire.io/dev/api/#webhook)

I personally don't like the word 'app', it feels a bit limited. Technially you can register any kind of server/service as an 'app' with quire. Then you can register webhooks to get notified once an event you subscribed for occurs. I.e. quire will call your server (via https) and your server can then execute a script in your favorite language: python, ruby, javascript, bash ...

As of now quire doesn't offer a service to upload your code into quire and execute there (just in case you intended to do that).